# latex: dollar $ sign within lstlising

Tags: math, latex, dollar-sign, lstlisting

I am trying to put some asm code into a latex document, onfurtunatly pdflatex treats the $ signs within my document as math env (which I do not want). On the other side I'd still like to use that fancy linebreak arrow (which uses math env to display it).

```
\lstset{
texcl=false,
mathescape=false,
..,
prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}}
}
```

example snap:

```
CTRL_WD_12      equ     $303400
CTRL_WD_34      equ     $220000
CTRL_WD_56      equ     $000000
CTRL_WD_78      equ     $000000
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try escaping the $ as \$

Comment: It's _a_lot_ of code.... so thats not really practical. Plus it ain't working, I get printed \$ when I do that. Thats the problem with lstlisting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing backslash.  Try:

```
prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}}
```

It was the `\hookleftarrow` outside of math mode that was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
CTRL_WD_12      equ     \$303400
CTRL_WD_34      equ     \$220000
CTRL_WD_56      equ     \$000000
CTRL_WD_78      equ     \$000000
```

The rule is: if something is a special character, like `$` is, a backslash `\` usually escapes it without problems.

Comment: @penguinpower: did you try setting `mathescape` to true?

Comment: that is default as far as I know