# latex - escape dollar sign inside lstlisting with [mathescape]

Tags: latex, tex, listings

I have a problem escaping the dollar sign in an mathescaped lstlisting environment

```
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
  $\delta$(Z, $\varepsilon$, $S) = (R, $\varepsilon$)
                             ^ 
\end{lstlisting}
```

With the help of an answer of a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448462) I got the idea to use another sign instead of the dollar sign like this:

```
\lstset{
  literate={\§}{{\textcolor{black}{\$}}}1
}
```

But when I used `\§` inside the listing I got `\$` instead of `$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\$` within math-mode (under `mathescape`) or `\mbox{\textdollar}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily, mathescape]
$\delta$(Z, $\varepsilon$, $\mbox{\textdollar}$S) = (R, $\varepsilon$)
$\delta$(Z, $\varepsilon$, $\$$S) = (R, $\varepsilon$)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```